# How good the average of a sample estimates the average.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be be a finite set with $n$ elements and let $f:X\to [c,d]$ be a function where $[c,d]$ in an interval in $\Bbb R$ and let $\epsilon > 0$ and the positive integer $m\le n$ be fixed.

For every $Y\subseteq X$, we let $M(Y)=\sum_{y\in Y}$f(y).

Let $\mathcal P_m(X)$ be the set of all subsets $Y\subseteq X$ with $|Y|=m$. Is there a way to approximate or calculate the probability that
$$\left |\frac{M(X)}{|X|}-\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}\right |\le \epsilon$$
when $Y$ is accidentally chosen from  $\mathcal P_m(X)$.

In fact, this probability shows if a sample with $m$ members is chosen from $X$, how good the average of the sample estimates the average of $X$.

The main problem is that there any incountably many functions $f$, and it seems hard to find a probability formula for all functions or the mean value of all probabilities for different $f$s.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the probability of the deviation from the true sample statistic does not have a nice general form for all $f$. You have very general conditions on $f$, so there will not be any such formula. I'll offer two suggestions:

**Option 1**

Since $X$ is finite, you can actually calculate this statistic exactly (in principle) under the assumption of simple random sampling of subsets $Y$:

1. There will be $K_m= {n \choose m}$ subsets in $\mathcal{P}_m(X)$.
2. For each $y \in \mathcal{P}_m(X)$, calculate $f(y)$ and record its value in a list $L_m$
3. Sort the items in $L_m$ from smallest to largest to get $L_m^*$
4. Divide each element in $L^*_m$ by $K_m$.
5. Now, if this is a theoretical study and you actually know $M(X)$, then you can subtract $\frac{M(X)}{|X|}$ from $L^*_m$ to get $\textrm{adj-}L^*_m$. This will give you a sorted list of deviations from the true population statistic. You can convert it to a distribution of absolute deviations by taking the absolute value of each element in $\textrm{adj-}L^*_m$ and then creating the cumulative distribution function from this list.
6. If you are actually performing inference, then you won't know $M(X)$, so you can apply bootstrapping by replacing $\frac{M(X)}{|X|}$ with $\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}$ (the statistic of the sample, and then proceeding with step $5$. This will be a bootstrap estimate of the absolute deviation statistic.

**Option 2**

If we assume that $f$ is bounded over $X$ and that $m,n$ are large (say, $\gg 30$), then the assumption of simple random sampling of subsets of $X$ suggests we can use the Central Limit Theorem to approximate the deviation:

1. For a given sample $Y\subseteq X$, calculate $\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}$ and calculate the [finite population sample standard deviation](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/11886/12171343/OnlineTopics/bbs12e_onlinetopic_ch07-6.pdf): $s_{m,n} = s_m\sqrt{\frac{n-m}{n-1}}$
2. Approximate the sampling distribution of the deviations by a gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,s_{m,n})$ (the mean is zero because the sample estimate is unbiased).
3. You can get the approximate cdf of the absolute deviations by taking advantage of the symmetry of the normal distribution.

$$P\left(\left |\frac{M(X)}{|X|}-\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}\right |\le \epsilon\right) \approx 2\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon}{s_{m,n}}\right)-1$$

Comment: Can you explain what $2\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon}{s_{m,n}}\right)-1$ is, in simple words?

Comment: @user795571. Sure thing. $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal density ($\mu=0,\sigma=1$). Now, since the argument in the LHS of the last equation is only positive, we are effectively reflecting the negative part of the normal density to the positive axis. This means that we expect the RHS to be 0 for $\epsilon =0$ and the RHS to approach 1 as $\epsilon \to \infty$. The formula in the argument of the RHS $\frac{\epsilon}{s_{n,m}}$ is just calculating the z-score of a give $\epsilon$ so we can plug it into the standard normal CDF.

Comment: Does $2\Phi\left(\frac{\epsilon}{s_{m,n}}\right)-1$ estimate the probability that $\left |\frac{M(X)}{|X|}-\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}\right |\le \epsilon$?

Comment: @user795571 it  *approximates* it by assuming that $\frac{1}{s_{m,n}}\left(\frac{M(X)}{|X|}-\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}\right)\; \dot{\sim} \;\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume $\frac{1}{s_{m,n}}\left(\frac{M(X)}{|X|}-\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}\right)\;$ has a normal distribution?

Comment: @user795571 see my first sentence under Option 2...it's not generally reasonable, but if we make some pragmatic assumptions, then yes, the normal approximation will probably be good. One can never be sure unless you do simulation studies for your hypothesized underlying distribution or if the resulting log-likelihood (again, for a presumed mode), is well approximated by a parabola.

Comment: The goal of the question is to check mathematically if estimating $\frac{M(X)}{|X|}$ by $\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}$ is reasonable. So if there is a calculable formula , e.g. $L(f,m,n,\epsilon)$, for the probability of holding $\left |\frac{M(X)}{|X|}-\frac{M(Y)}{|Y|}\right |\le \epsilon$, then we can check many cases exactly to see the result or we may understand which $f$s are acceptable for such estimation or we may find the mathematical expectation of $L(f,m,n,\epsilon)$ as $f$ varies freely (uniformly).

Comment: The main point is to have a mathematical exactness for estimation, instead of intuition. But it seems you are losing this exactness by another even vaguer estimation. It is acceptable if there is a reasonable approximation for $L(f,m,n,\epsilon)$ but it has to be mathematically reasonable. that is, we must be able to explain why this approximation is good and how good it is.

Comment: @user795571 I don't follow your comments. My first option outlines exactly what you said (exact tests). The second options employs standard asymptotic methods to demonstrate reasonableness in without the need to specify a particular $f$.